# Remove input line in telnet session

Tags: python, telnet, gevent

Is it possible to remove the input line in a telnet session from the buffer, so when you press enter, the text you typed is removed, but still sent to the telnet server?

I know there is a way to send a certain char that moves the cursor to the beginning of the line and then overwrite the line with a new one, but since the new line chatacter is put into the buffer, I can't go past that. Is there a way to work around this?

Example: (The second line is user input)

```
Welcome to my imba text game!
pick up axe
```

Then you press enter and the screen buffer reads:

```
Welcome to my imba mud game!
[You picked up the axe]
```

**Update:**

I think the key is to set the telnet client in some mode that does not echo the local input. 
I found that sending some magic chars to the client can change the mode. I found this example and i don't know what it means but it prevents input from showing in the telnet client. However the input is never sent to the server so it is just half the answer.

```
socket.send("\377\375\042\377\373\001")
```

Maybe it's because I'm reading input line by line. I would like it to be read as char by char. Don't know how to modify this to do that though:

```
fileobj = socket.makefile()
while True:
    line = fileobj.readline()
    ...
```

Comment: Is it not possible or is my question vague?

Answer (score 1):

I think, this problem has no special connection with gevent, since it's socket API is similar to the original socket module. And the question isn't affected by the gevent's quazi-parallel greenletes execution.
Try to use socket.recv() instead of fileobj.readline().

Answer (score 0):

I did end up using socket.rscv() but I don't know if that mattered. The solution was this magic sequens of negotiation chars that I just send to the telnet client upon connecting:

```
socket.send(chr(0xff) + chr(0xfb) + chr(0x01) + chr(0xff) + chr(0xfb) + chr(0x03) + chr(0xff) + chr(0xfd) + chr(0x0f3))
```

It basically tells the client to use char by char mode and turf off local echoing. In that way, when I receive a char, i append it to a lineBuffer and sends it back with a "\r" prefix, to overwrite the last line. If the char is a return char, I parse the lineBuffer. Works great!